# Getting substring ignoring numeric indices

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following two strings:

```
var block = "//div[@class='gd-row browse-grid-row'][1]/div[@class='gd-col gu3'][1]/div"

var full =  "//div[@class='gd-row browse-grid-row'][1]/div[@class='gd-col gu3'][2]/div[@class='product-unit unit-4 browse-product new-design ']/div[@class='pu-details lastUnit']/div[@class='pu-price']/div[@class='pu-border-top']/div[@class='pu-final']/span"
```

I need to check if block is a substring of full ignoring all indices.

Basically i want to ignore all patterns of the form:

'[number]'

when checking for substring. 
How do I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: You could use regex to remove `[number]` and then check from there. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `str.replace(/\[\d*\]/g, '')`

Comment: I am not very familiar with regex. I was trying to put in conditionals to do the check! Didn't think of replace. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use `replace` and `indexOf`:

```
var regex = regex = /\[\d+\]/g;

full.replace(regex, '').indexOf(block.replace(regex, '')) > -1
```